# Joomla and Google Analytics advanced options in tracking code

Tags: google-analytics, joomla

I want to insert google analytics tracking code in my joomla site.

so i registered in the official site of google and saw there is an advanced tab with three more options than standard.

Do i have to check "i want to track dynamic pages" and "i want to track php pages"? Do these options provide me better results or they are necessary for a dynamic site based on php like joomla?
Does anyone know the process of installing? because i didn't manage to make it work by following [this](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=431&t=499232&view=next)

Also where do i place the tracking code? Because of some bugs some say it is better just after the tag `<body>` whereas other say just before the tag `</body>`.

Thank you

Comment: You've lost a couple of words - "after the tag". If you put in the missing word (I'm guessing it's either head or body) then highlight it and press ctrl-K then it won't get swallowed up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case I didn't bother with any additional details and I recommend that your don't either based on your experience. Best to just go with the default options.

Copy and paste the following snippet on the last line just before `</body>`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-X']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();    
</script>
```

Also ensure that you fill `UA-XXXXX-` with the user-id issued by Google Analytics.